Python property with change type of value and correct work with mypy
I try to learn how to work with class property correctly
import datetime

from typing import ClassVar


class TestProperty(object):

    today: ClassVar[datetime.datetime] = datetime.datetime.today()

    def __init__(self, start: str):
        self.start = start

    @property
    def start(self) -> datetime.datetime:
        return self._start

    @start.setter
    def start(self, value: str) -> None:
        start_h, start_m = [int(val) for val in value.split(":")]
        self._start: datetime.datetime = TestProperty.today.replace(hour=start_h, minute=start_m)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tp = TestProperty("12:00")
    print(tp.start)

And I got a warning to my code from mypy's side to this string
self.start = start

Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "datetime")
How to correctly solve this warning?

You hinted that self.start is of type datetime.datetime yet you assign a str to it

Maybe exist right way to transform string to datetime with help Python property?

Related: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/12892

The issue seems to stem from the use of a setter during __init__ although I confess that I can't provide an explanation as to why that would happen.
If you write a helper function to carry out the string and datetime conversion you can overcome the problem like this (with some simplifications):
from datetime import datetime

class TestProperty():
    today: datetime = datetime.today()

    def __init__(self, value: str):
        self._start = self.convert(value)
    
    def convert(self, value: str) -> datetime:
        hh, mm = map(int, value.split(":"))
        return self.today.replace(hour=hh, minute=mm)
    
    @property
    def start(self) -> datetime:
        return self._start

    @start.setter
    def start(self, value: str) -> None:
        self._start = self.convert(value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tp = TestProperty("12:00")
    print(tp.start)


I think the best you can do, in light of the "split" type of self.start (depending on whether you are doing lookup or assignment), is to use cast to tell the type checker to pretend that the str is a datetime.datetime.
from typing import cast


class TestProperty:
    ...

    def __init__(self, start: str):
        self.start = cast(datetime.datetime, start)

    ...

You know that TypeProperty.start.fset takes a str; mypy just needs a little help to recognize that.
In the broader sense, it's probably a better idea to make the caller provide a datetime.datetime, instead of making the setter do type conversion.

Interestingly, although this solves the mypy issue, pylance is unhappy about it viz. "datetime" is not assignable to "str'

Oof, looks like PyRight does handle the "split type" correctly. No idea how to make it work in both type checkers.
